# sudo apt update Error 403 Forbidden [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]

Tags: 18.04

I get error using sudo apt update

```
Err:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
```

or when try to install putty

```
Err:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 putty-tools amd64 0.70-4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I connected to another wi-fi and successfully updated system and installed putty. I don't know what was wrong.

Comment: It might have been your other connection acting up!